# Convert JSON to shapefile

Tags: json, gis

I have a json file that contains a lot of data with polygons, lines, points. But I can't exploit it to export the data in shapefile. Can someone help me on how to get there. The data is here.
https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/produits-numeriques-en-libre-disposition/donnees-zones-geographiques-uas.html

if someone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: Which programming languages? What look like your code? I didn't check the link but it may be GeoJSON, so many tools can read it

Answer (score 0):

You can't export all of it to **one** shapefile as it is not possible to mix geometry types in a shapefile, so you will need 3 shapefiles (points, lines, polygons).

I would make use of [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) the Swiss army knife of vector formats and use something like:

```
ogr2ogr -nlt POINT -skipfailures points.shp geojsonfile.json     
ogr2ogr -nlt LINESTRING -skipfailures linestrings.shp geojsonfile.json 
ogr2ogr -nlt POLYGON -skipfailures polygons.shp geojsonfile.json
```